# DBM or SQLite in PHP 5.x

Tags: php, sqlite, content-management-system, dbm

We have a client whose site is hosted on a server (I don't want to disclose hosting company name) which does not provide DB functionality.

We have developed a very simple CMS based site but out implementation uses MySQL.

I read somewhere that there are DB like functionality built-in in PHP. I have never used them.

What are these and how reliable are they?

What is more advisable to user the DBM functionality or to use the SQLite functionality?

For SQLite do we have to make any changes to php.ini file? If *yes* then this is *out of bounce* for us as the hosting provider does not give us access to php.ini file.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite is shipped as default with PHP 5.2.x. I would prefer SQLite because it supports nearly the same sql commands like MySQL and is realy fast.

Altough there is a nice GUI for SQLite for Firefox provided as Plugin. (SqliteManager).

Answer (score 1):

The DBM is not a relational database system (no SQL), so it would be difficult to port your CMS. SQLite at least has an SQL support. You may find more information about DBM at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBM_(computing)

Comment: Actually the CMS is never going to contain more than 100 dynamic pages at any point of time. But I will surely give SQLite a look if it will work on server.